# ScrewTurn Wiki SQL data provider plugin?

Tags: c#, sql, plugins, wiki, screwturn

[Here](http://www.screwturn.eu/Download.ashx) you can download either a SQL server based, compiled solution, or the source code which stores data in a rather primitive way (file-system data storage). I want to use the source code since I intend to modify it, but I still want to store the data in SQL Server, in their site I couldn't find any "plugin" which would do this, so I was wondering if anyone has developed a version that already interfaces with SQL server *AND* is open source.

Comment: It is OSS. IIRC, the SQL stuff is also there. No need for a plugin.

Comment: What does OSS stand for? So many acronyms!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As leppie mentioned, everything is open-source, including the SQL Server providers, which are included in the source package.

Note: you should use [our forum](http://www.screwturn.eu/forum) to ask questions, as it surely gets more attention from us.

Comment: from OP's Download url: "ScrewTurn Wiki 3.0.5.600, pre-configured for storing data in a SQL Server database."

Comment: @devio, yeah, but that package is pre-compiled.